# How to modify a module installed from marketplace?

Tags: php, magento2

there are some behaviors in a module that i installed from Marketplace that i want to change a bit, like adding some more configurations, overriding template files and add a bit more Javascript, stylings, etc. I'm not seeing anywhere i can extend from a 3rd party module installed from Marketplace, what would be the best practices to deal with this? As i don't really want to modify the extension's code. I'm using Magento 2.

Edit:
This is what i tried:

I checked the module name in registration.php, name is Mynamespace_Mymodule for example I then created app/code/Mynamespace/Mymodule/

I tried adding a template file in app/code/Mynamespace/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/viewfile.phtml

viewfile.phtml is available in vendor/ with the same path as well, what else should i add to make it use my viewfile.phtml instead of the module's?

Comment: Is it Magento module or smth else?

Comment: Magento 2 module installed through composer, so the module is placed in vendor/ directory, i now want to override certain parts of the module, by placing my own code in app/code/ directory

Comment: use all customization method as usual,  for preference use NameSpace/ModuleName approach

Comment: in different words no matter code located in vendor or app/code

Comment: This is what i tried:

I checked the module name in registration.php, name is Mynamespace_Mymodule for example

I then created app/code/Mynamespace/Mymodule/

I tried adding a template file in app/code/Mynamespace/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/viewfile.phtml

viewfile.phtml is available in vendor/ with the same file path as well, what else should i add to make it use my viewfile.phtml instead of the module's?

Comment: I just added what i tried to my question for more clarification

Comment: try yournamespace/yourmodule/vendornamespace_vendor module/templates/viewfile.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override any modules that you like (whether they are core Magento, or installed via composer / 3rd party).

## Overriding Classes

To override a module's behavior, you must create your own custom module with whatever namespace you like. `Testing_Extension` for example. There is a few files at minimum required to create a module in order to have your Magento 2 installation recognize it as such:

1. A `registration.php` file in the root of your module (`Testing/Extension/registration.php`) to define the module name. Without this you will not be able to enable your extension from the CLI, it is required by Magento 2.
2. An `etc/module.xml` file to define the module setup version and name.

If you have created those files with the correct format and placed them in the `app\code` directory, you will be able to use the command `php bin/magento module:enable Testing_Extension` to enable it, followed by a `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command to register your module with the Magento store. This will add an entry in the database table setup_modules that you can refer to.

Now you're ready to have your module do something. To have it take precedence over your 3rd party extension, you'll need to create what's called a "class preference" so that Magento will know which code to choose from (yours or the 3rd party). Without this preference Magento will not know what you want to do.

To create a preference, you'll need to create a `di.xml` file in your etc directory to look like the following:

```
<config>
   <preference for="Example\Extension\Class\Name" type="Testing\Extension\Class\Name" />
</config>
```

Now just create that class and you will be set. This will allow to override any class you want. You will need to recompile using `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` after you write your code.

## Overriding Views

You mention wanting to override a `viewfile.phtml` file, which is extremely straight forward. You will need to have a child theme created in `app/design/Theme/Name` with the necessary files there ([you can read more about theme inheritance here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html)). Once that's completed you can override any `.phtml` templates by simply creating the directory names in there. Here's how you would do that:

1. Navigate to `app/design/Child/Theme`
2. Create directory `Example_Extension` to directly override the default viewfile.phtml that Magento would normally load.
3. Inside of that directory create another directory `templates`
4. Create `viewfile.phtml` and make the edits you would like.
5. View the page where that template is rendered, and you will see your changes there instead of the default from the 3rd party module.

Done! You can override any frontend templates in the Theme itself, and any other back-end code with a class preference. Be sure to post any follow-up comments or questions if you have any, would be happy to address those for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, i thought there would be a way to accomplish this without writing a custom module, but looks like i will have to create one eventually. Just not sure if it's a common practice to do it like that, is it common to want to change certain small behaviors in Magento extensions so we will just create our own custom modules to extend from them??

Comment: @LongMKNguyễn No problem at all! Yes, this is the standard method to follow for making changes to how Magento core or the 3rd party modules operate. To reiterate from my post, if it's just a frontend view you want to modify it can be done within a theme rather than creating an entire module for a single template file.